# "Citizen" Badge

Tags: feature-request, badge-request

Just a few minutes ago, in "Philosophy," I earned the voting privilege. That was thanks to writing an answer, getting it upvoted, and having my answer accepted by the asker. You who have been in these forums for a long time might forget what a rush that is for a newbie. Going to the help, I saw there were many "voting" type badges, but I saw what looks to me to be a glaring omission: The "Citizen Badge." It means you have the right to vote. It's an important milestone.

At least, for me. But probably many others.

Here's why.

I joined Stack Overflow because my google searches for various C language related tasks were finding Stack Overflow at the top of the heap, again, and again, and again. Google likes you!

And, again, and again, and again I was seeing some incredibly detailed, thoughtful, and courteous answers. It was *incredibly* useful. Naturally, I wanted to thank the posters and upvote their responses. But no! I had no rep!

Further, I'm pretty good at searching. It is *very* rare that I can't find the answer to a question. But I saw I'd never gain any rep without getting involved. So I accepted the challenge.

It is difficult finding and writing *good* questions. Maybe, when I move from a beginner to an intermediate C coder, this may change. I hope so. I hope to be able to help others too, but at this time, I am so outclassed, there is little hope of that in the programming forums. (I have, in fact, discovered a couple questions that do not seem to have answers specific enough. I'll be posting at least one fairly soon.)

But, at this writing, I still can't upvote on Stack Overflow. It's frustrating to not be able to properly acknowledge people who've answered questions. Heck, my initial motivation for joining Stack Overflow was just so I could do that. It's important to me to be able to show some love that way. A lot of people really put some serious effort into their answers. So, to me, that voting privilege is Very Big Deal. I think it deserves more recognition.

My background is in classical languages, literature, and classical history. I'm always throwing in these little tidbits when it seems apropos. Here's one:

In ancient Athens—assuming your pedigree was sound (and you were male, sorry)—you earned your citizen privilege when you were twelve. You may not have known much. You may not have been very useful, you were probably not quite familiar with all the rules, but it meant you were counted with the adults. I'm using my "Meta Privilege" to suggest a "Citizen Badge." It comes with the voting privilege.

[Er, I just thought of something. If something like this *were* to implemented, it would have a retroactive impact on thousands (upon thousands?) of users. NOT trivial!]

Comment: You know that there is already a badge for making use of the right to vote (as well as one for making use of the right to downvote)?

Comment: I did see that. Somehow "Supporter" did not have the same ring. What I'm suggesting undercuts that a bit? And "Critic" did not seem desirable at all!

Comment: Tangentially related: I checked your questions on [SO], and if I had considered them worth upvoting I would do so to give you the upvote privilege there. (I don't normally vote targeting a user, except to give someone a deserved boost on their first few rep.) One of your questions is very long - *too* long IMO - and in the other, I can't tell what you're actually asking. The point: perhaps some edits to your questions will improve them to the point where more people upvote them, and then you will have your 15 reputation easily. After all you only need one more vote!

Comment: Well, thanks for looking. I'll keep asking questions and trying to provide answers.

Comment: @DavidZ. I pondered your critique, btw. I came to an interesting conclusion. The less I know what I'm talking about, the more verbose I tend to be. So, thanks. I'd up vote your comment if I could. :)

Answer (score 4):

At the age of 12, a child may have been a "citizen", but certainly could not vote solely because of that. In order for a citizen to be able to vote in ancient Athens, they had to go through military training. This is probably why the percent of the population that actually participated in the government was so low.

Luckily Stack Exchange is not so brutal! All it requires is 15 reputation to vote, and no one will require that you fight a war for them nor discriminate you based on bias.

I know you must have a strong desire to upvote all the things and give back. But really, upvoting everything all at once is not desirable because it can be seen as serial voting and the system may remove them all.

Participating in the Stack Exchange community will allow you to give back, and all you to have is patience :)

As for the badge idea, I am not sure that it would be much different than supporter (first cast up vote), and since this was a feature-request you may get downvotes from users indicating they do not want the badge added.

In general, new badges are supposed to encourage behaviors not necessarily be rewards - and also, vetting the community for the type of behavior a badge will encourage is usually good practice before putting in a feature request.

Comment: Heh. I see my question did get downvoted. Thanks for the answer. Yes, I see that the badges are rewards for behavior. That makes sense.

Comment: @RichardG.Crockett - feature-requests kind of have their own style of voting on meta, basically instead of voicing yes or no, or always including those options, people tend to +1 or -1 to show agreement. Try not to take it personally :) In my opinion your question was very well written.

Comment: I've got a thick skin. :) I just hope I don't end up burning what little karma I have because I out it out there, disagreeable or not.

Comment: @RichardG.Crockett - I don't think that will be the case. While these do get some downvotes, usually people will not "pile on" to them at a certain point, especially not with such a considerate proposal. Also, it is looked down upon to follow a user from a meta post to their main posts and downvote there. That is called "the meta affect" (especially when a post is linked in a post here). In the long run, this will be but a small blip. Heck, I have had way worse requests when I was new here :)

Answer (score 2):

With great power comes great responsibility, but the power is only as good as your use of it.

There are a whole bunch of milestones that a user can attain via rep - voting, participating on meta, protecting questions, accessing review queues - the list goes on. As a site gets older, it beings to accumulate users who have these privileges, and so they take a more active role in running the site.

The problem is, there are users - not many, I'll grant you, but some all the same - who don't use these privileges. Perhaps they don't participate on meta, or review a bunch of posts, or vote to close or re-open questions. That's fine; it's their choice.

Badges are rewards, though, for actions you've done on the site. You earn badges for reviewing, voting, asking good questions and answers, posting comments, and a host of other things. You get rewards for participating on the site, not simply using it. If this badge were to be created, people could get an undeserved badge just by having one really great post, while not contributing much to the community. The name "citizen" would be accurate - you can become one even if you don't vote, or care about the site/country.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation. Just learning the ropes. Thanks for the thoughtful reply.

Comment: After reading both yours and @Travis J's responses, I feel this question has been fully answered. Now I think, "No. This not needed. Badges should be about action and behavior." I'd like to accept _both_ answers because together they flesh out a description of the system in a way I now understand much better. It has been enlightening.